# Dynamic variables, CALLERS, Scalars, and assignment

Tags: variable-assignment, raku, dynamic-variables, rakudo

I recently noticed that that re-initializing dynamic variables does not have the semantics I expected in most cases using assignment (binding works the way I expected it to, however).

Specifically, in this code:

```
sub g {
    my $*i  = CALLERS::<$*i>  // 0;
    my $*a1 = CALLERS::<$*a1> // Array.new;
    my @*a2 = CALLERS::<@*a2> // Array.new;
    $*i++;
    $*a1.push: 'v1';
    @*a2.push: 'v2';
    dd $*i;
    dd $*a1;
    dd @*a2;
}
sub f {
    my $*i = 0;
    my $*a1 = Array.new;
    my @*a2 = Array.new;
    g; g; g;
}
f
```

I expected output of `3`, `["v1", "v1", "v1"]`, and `["v2", "v2", "v2"]` but instead get `1`, `$["v1", "v1", "v1"]`, `["v2"]`.  Switching to binding solves the issue, so there's no problem I'm trying to solve – but I would very much like to understand *why* assignment doesn't work here.  I notice that a Scalar pointing to an Array works, but a Scalar pointing to an Int doesn't.  But in either case, I would have thought that the newly assigned variable would receive the value from CALLERS.  What am I missing about the semantics of assignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I missing about the semantics of assignment?

I think what you're missing, doesn't have anything to do with dynamic variables per se.  I think what you're missing is the fact that:

```
my @a = Array.new;
```

is basically a noop.  Because of the single argument rule, it is the same as:

```
my @a = ();
```

which is the same as:

```
my @a;
```

So, in your example in `sub f`, the:

```
my @*a2 = Array.new;
```

in is just setting up an empty array in a dynamic variable.

Then in `sub g` the:

```
my @*a2 = CALLERS::<@*a2> // Array.new;
```

is just basically doing (because of the single argument rule):

```
my @*a2;
```

and hence you don't see the `push`es you've done before, because every call it starts out fresh.

Regarding the value of `$*i` in `sub g`: that also is just incrementing a *copy* of the callers `$*i`, so the value remains at `1` in every call.

The reason that `$*a1` works, is that containerization stops the flattening behaviour of the single argument rule.  Observe the difference between:

```
sub a(+@a) { dd @a }; a [2,3,4];  # [2,3,4]
```

and:

```
sub a(+@a) { dd @a }; a $[2,3,4];  # [[2,3,4],]
```